# After installing php on nGinX phpinfo() works but nothing else

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php

After installing nGinX on Ubuntu 12.04, installing PHP and setting up my vhosts to run PHP I created a file called test.php, but only the php info is displaying not the echoed text.

This is the content of my test file

```
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   <?

   echo 'hello php test';

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't noticed that I switched to short tags while writing this script. After changing my short tags **`<?`** to long tags **`<?php`** the php echoed the string correctly.

I am migrating a bunch of php files to the new server with short tags, so I needed to enable short tags in my php.ini file.

To do that I updated the following line within the php.ini file

**short_open_tag = On**

Next I had to restart nginx

**sudo service nginx restart**

Comment: I think you don't need to restart nginx, you just need to reload the php settings. `service php5-fpm reload`, ps: use `reload` instead of `restart`, It wont terminate all connections and restart.